# how rank is calculated in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rank

I confuse to understand rank of series. I know that rank is calculated from the highest value to lowest value in a series. If two numbers are equal, then pandas calculates the average of the numbers.

In this example, the highest value is 7. why do we get rank 5.5 for number 7 and rank 1.5 for number 4 ?

```
S1 = pd.Series([7,6,7,5,4,4])
S1.rank()

Output:

0    5.5
1    4.0
2    5.5
3    3.0
4    1.5
5    1.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: 4 is ranked as #1 and #2, average being 1.5. 7 is ranked #5 and #6, average being 5.5.

Comment: how 1.5 and 5.5 comes here ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Rank is calculated in this way

1. Arrange the elements in ascending order and the ranks are assigned starting with '1' for the lowest element.

> ```
> Elements - 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7
> Ranks    - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
> ```

2. Now consider the repeating items, average out the corresponding ranks and assign the averaged rank to them.

Since we have '4' repeating twice, the final rank of each occurrence will be the average of 1,2 which is 1.5.
In the same way or 7, final rank for each occurrence will be average of 5,6 which is 5.5

> ```
> Elements -   4,   4,   5, 6, 7,   7
> Ranks    -   1,   2,   3, 4, 5,   6
> Final Rank - 1.5, 1.5, 3, 4, 5.5, 5.5
> ```

Comment: can you show the calculation of average for same number??

Comment: updated the answer. The default method in Pandas calculates like this. but there are other methods of calculating Rank, as in @Quang Hoang's answer

Comment: @vvv - thanks for the response. do pandas rank() always sort the rank order in ascending internally for calculation ???

Comment: It won't sort the rank order.  It internally sorts the values of your series first and then assigns ranks as per the method you specified and gives back the result w.r.t the Series index.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by Joachim, the `rank` function accepts an argument `method` with default `'average'`. That is, the final rank is the average of all the rank of the same values.

Per the document, other options of `method` are:

> method : {'average', 'min', 'max', 'first', 'dense'}, default
> 'average'
> How to rank the group of records that have the same value
> (i.e. ties):
>
> - average: average rank of the group
> - min: lowest rank in the group
> - max: highest rank in the group
> - first: ranks assigned in order they appear in the array
> - dense: like 'min', but rank always increases by 1 between groups numeric_only : bool, optional

For example, let's try: `method='dense'`, then `S1.rank(method='dense')` gives:

```
0    4.0
1    3.0
2    4.0
3    2.0
4    1.0
5    1.0
dtype: float64
```

which is somewhat equivalent to `factorize`.

---

**Update**: per your question, let's try writing a function that behaves similar to `S1.rank()`:

```
def my_rank(s):
    # sort s by values
    s_sorted = s.sort_values(kind='mergesort')

    # this is the incremental ranks
    # equivalent to s.rank(method='first')
    ranks = pd.Series(np.arange(len(s_sorted))+1, index=s_sorted.index)

    # averaged ranks
    avg_ranks = ranks.groupby(s_sorted).transform('mean')

    return avg_ranks
```

Answer (score 2):

You were performing default rank if you want max rank the follow as below

```
S1 = pd.Series([7,6,7,5,4,4])
S1.rank(method='max')
```

Here is all rank supported by pandas

methods : {‘average’, ‘min’, ‘max’, ‘first’, ‘dense’}, and default is ‘average’

```
S1['default_rank'] = S1.rank()
S1['max_rank'] = S1.rank(method='max')
S1['NA_bottom'] = S1.rank(na_option='bottom')
S1['pct_rank'] = S1.rank(pct=True)
print(S1)
```

Comment: 6,4,6,3,2,2 is the max rank that i get.Why dont we have rank 5 and 1 ??

Comment: Try S1.rank(method='min')